Reality Capture API is throwing error. not generating the results
I want to convert my images of an object to 3d model (2d images to 3d image).
I used Reality capture API's. which is not working, files are uploaded properly and progress is 100% with error message. i uploaded 25 images of an object.
I try to give multiple object data, but still no luck. I try throw postman, curl and Nodejs example code.
I follow https://aps.autodesk.com/developer/idea/recap-app
and https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/hitchhikers-guide-reality-capture-api articles,
here is my code: https://github.com/usmanmanii/Reality-Capture-Api-example


Please [edit] your question to specifically and clearly define the problem that you are trying to solve. Additional details — including all relevant code, error messages, and debugging logs — will help readers to better understand your problem and [what you are asking].

i added more detail

Please [edit] your question to include a [mre] so that readers can run your code to answer your question.

yes i provide that code Github link, this is not issue with code, it's issue in Autodesk API's, and in order to run the code you have to run my code which mention in description, it's the sequence of API's which authenticate you then you will be able to hit desire API's.

"yes i provide that code Github link" - If this links dissapears, then the whole question is worth nothing

this is my public repository, how can it will be disappear ? there is too much content, i can't upload the whole file here.

Then you should only post the relevant code - "there is too much content", you don't expect people here to go through the whole code base to pinpoint the problem for you?

After a lot of effort, I found a solution. I send a different value to "scenetype" equal to "object" and "format" equal to "obj,fbx". Which resolve my issue.
here is the example code in nodejs (Click Here)
here is the postman collection (Click Here)
You can use this photoscreen which shared by @denis-grigor (Click Here)
Thank you denis-grigor for you feedback.

I looked into images you have in your repo and I think the problem is in images.
You have 25 images, but those images are for 5 different objects. The algorithm works by stitching images belonging to the same object. You cannot just throw dozens of images belonging to several different objects and get several mesh results. It works just with one object and only images pertinent to that object.

Thanks for helping, In my repository, I uploaded various images, but interestingly, I found myself using the same object images across different scenarios. Surprisingly, the issue wasn’t related to the images themselves. Instead, it centered around the ‘scenetype’ property, which isn’t mandatory. By default, it was set to ‘aerial,’ causing consistent failures. However, when I switched it to ‘object,’ everything fell into place, and I finally got the expected results.
